# preg_replace(): The /e modifier is deprecated, use preg_replace_callback instead

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-replace-callback

I have a problem. This is what I have:

```
$file_contents = preg_replace("!{$ldq}\*.*?\*{$rdq}!se","",$file_contents);
```

And I get a error saying that I need to replace preg_replace with preg_replace callback.
And when I try to make it to  preg_replace_callback this is what I end up with:

```
$file_contents = preg_replace_callback(
    "!{$ldq}\*.*?\*{$rdq}!se",
    function($matches) {
          return "";
    },
    $file_contents);
```

And then I end up with a new error saying

```
preg_replace_callback(): Modifier /e cannot be used with replacement callback
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Don't use the `e` switch in the regexp for your preg_replace_callback(), simply `"!{$ldq}\*.*?\*{$rdq}!s",`

Comment: You do not get an _error_, you get a _notice_ or a _warning_. If the flag is deprecated that does not mean it does not work.

Comment: in the present case you don't need the e modifier at all since your replacement is a fixed string (an empty string here), so remove it, that's all: `preg_replace("!{$ldq}\*.*?\*{$rdq}!s", "", $file_contents);`